# exec: 94: /hsphere/shared/php5/bin/php: not found when upgrading magento

Tags: php, magento-1.4

When i upgrading magento site from older version to latest version i got some error in shell.

I followed this link to upgrade magento:

http://turnkeye.com/blog/magento-upgrade-guide/

first entered :

```
chmod -R 777 lib/PEAR
```

then i  entered the commmand:

```
./pear mage-setup
```

then i got this errors:

[image]

what is this error?

How can i solve this?

EDIT:
[image]

after completing the upgrading and took the site url in browser got this error:

[image]

Comment: could you do a `whereis php` ?

Comment: i cant understabnd .what you meand?

Comment: on the console, type `whereis php`.

Comment: i got this `php: /usr/bin/php /usr/share/php /usr/share/man/man1/php.1.gz` after entered `whereis php`

Comment: I don't have a 1.4.x installation here right now, but can you open the  `pear` file (type `vi pear` on the console)? If so, is there a line that says something like `MAGE_PHP_BIN="php"`? If so, try changing it to `MAGE_PHP_BIN="/usr/bin/php"`

Comment: yes i can open the pear file and i got a screen.the screen recieved is displayed in the edit prt of the question.i added the screen shot in last of question.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/14608/discussion-between-mariya-davis-and-florian)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that under the path `/hsphere/shared/php5/bin/php` there's nothing to be found on your server.

The problem is within you pear installer script. Open it (e.g. with `nano pear`) and change the `MAGE_PEAR_PHP_BIN="/hsphere/shared/php5/bin/php"` to `MAGE_PEAR_PHP_BIN="/usr/bin/php"`.

After that, installation should be possible.

lg,

flo

(Notice: Answer as provided in chat)

Comment: after that took the site url ,it is loading for sometime after that it displays errors.the error screen shot is on the last of the question .

Comment: do you have any idea?if there is any solution for this error?

Comment: It is a database related error you have gotten your hands on here, the error is actually presented and means that there is a key in you db for which exists duplicate data, which is more of content problem now than an actual engineering task

Comment: i solved thta upgraded into magento latest version.but in admin panel the menu bar not displaying